# Can I have non-evil blood mages?

Tags: society, religion, gods

I'm creating a world in which an entire continent is constructed from a monster. Drawing from Aztec mythos, I have named this creature Cipactli, and though it was slain, it's still, to an extent, alive. In accordance with the Aztec myths, It needs to be sated with blood. However, I want to divide the continent. I want followers of Cipactli to be trying to resurrect it. I want a rival group of people trying to keep it asleep. However, I don't know how to do this while keeping sacrifices on both sides. Cipactli needs to be sated to stay asleep, but if it's woken up by being deprived of sacrifices, its followers aren't going to stop sacrifices to Cipactli.

If it helps, the continent has a magic system, whereby sacrificing blood you may convince Cipactli to move its coils and therefore the terrain. idk how that would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking : Do you want to know how Cipactli is not woken up by the "good" guys, yet it is by the "bad" guys?

Comment: Also, is this this [Cipactli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipactli) you're talking about, or is it a pure creation of your own and we can't rely on this reference to answer?

Comment: If Cipactli can be persuaded to move its coils *quickly*, you have a way of causing earthquakes as weapons of war. I suggest that you don't make this easy, if you want any kind of functioning civilization.

Comment: VTC: I want to answer this question! But I don't know *anything* about your magic system other than sacrifice is involved. Animal vs. human sacrifice. Complimentary sacrifice (you "sacrifice" the pig before cooking and eating it) vs. contradictory sacrifice (you whack as many as you can as quick as you can and throw the offal on the bonfire!) What binds followers to the creature? What is the nature of the religion? I could ask a dozen more questions. VTC until you give us more detail.

Comment: BTW, if you read through our [help], you'll discover that we're willing to help you make rules and build your world, but we're not willing to help you overcoem writer's block. If you can't help us with information about the structure and implementation of the magic system... if you're just looking for ideas to help you continue writing... then this isn't the right place to ask. If you want help *developing that magic system,* we're great at that! But we'll need conditions, limitaitons, restrictions, expectations, and goals to place bounds on our answers.

Comment: Do you even need to kill the victim?   If everyone in the city puts a drop of blood on the stone, does it suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I might be in need of some more information to answer your question the way you will want it answered, however I'll enjoy taking a stab at it.

Perhaps you need to answer for yourself if all sacrifices have the same effect on Cipactli.  It sounds like they can currently be used for specific purposes if you know what you're doing like moving terrain, so perhaps the number of/type of/manner in which sacrifices are made will affect whether Cipactli awakens or sleeps.  I would imagine that Cipactli being slain in the past means that it would take a lot of effort, resources, sacrifices, and powerful magic to overcome the traditional sacrifices that made him fall/keep him asleep.

If Cipactli needs to be sated to remain asleep, perhaps the group that is trying to wake him up is doing sacrifices differently.  Maybe the group keeping him asleep lets the sacrificial blood reach the soil where it can be absorbed and sate him, while the rival group only wants him to smell sacrifices or for him to sense there are sacrifices he is being deprived of.  So maybe they're burning sacrifices or throwing them to the ocean where other predators enjoy them instead of him.  Maybe specific rituals are meant to augment his hunger during the sacrifices so he can only taste the sacrifice but not absorb the energy from it.

It could be helpful if you tell us more about how you've decided sacrificial magic works in your world or what you need help fleshing out (ba dum tiss)

Answer (score 0):

**Human Sacrifice**

What do you sacrifice? Animals. What else can you sacrifice? Humans. Of the two, which is the evil one?

Obviously the good guys sacrifice animals and the bad guys sacrifice people. Both sacrifices let you cast spells but the human sacrifices start waking the Cipactli up while the animals put him into a deeper sleep.

A recurring theme of the story is whether Cipactli is a good guy or a bad guy. The baddies want to wake him up so maybe he is also a baddie? Maybe he should stay dead?

The twist is that Cipactli is a goodie. One day he lay down in the ocean so his children (humans) could flourish on his body. He told people to be nice, and  he would only wake up if they did too much bloodshed. This is why the baddies are sacrificing people.

The baddies want to start the war to end all wars. They think it is for the best is humans are all wiped out when the continent wakes up, rather than lingering on for thousands of years of small war after small war.

The theme of the second part is what makes someone a goodie or a baddie. If you have good intentions, do the ends justify the means?